Databricks Spark structured streaming metrics rows written per batch
I have a streaming job in Databricks that looks like the following:

Read input stream (single table) with readStream

Call forEachBatch to do some processing

Inside forEachBatch, I have a code that produces multiple datasets and writes each of them to their target delta table (single source -> multiple sinks) using
 df.write.format("delta").mode("append").save(<location>)



I want to collect some metrics per batch to see number of input rows and number of rows written to each target.
When it comes to rows written, I can get that information from Spark UI, but I don't know whether it's possible to collect the information about rows written to each target.
Any suggestions?
